# Print a dictionary only keys without brackets and quotation marks

Tags: python

```
myDict = {"1" : "Gorilla", "2" : "Place", "3" : "Place to learn"}
```

So, I want to print out a dictionary. But I want to do it like it looks like an actual list of things. I can't just do print myDict, as it will leave all the ugly stuff in. I want the output to look like

```
> 1234
```

So what do I do? I haven't found a post meeting what I want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for x in myDict: print(x,end="")` would suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
print("".join(myDict.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_output(adict):
    for key, value in adict.items():
        print(key, value)

#given input
myDict = {"1" : "Gorilla", "2" : "Place", "3" : "Place to learn"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_output(myDict)
```

```
1 Gorilla
2 Place
3 Place to learn
```

Comment: This solution does not answer the question

Comment: @Thekingis007 - They edited the question.